# How to capture an event, when TTreeview structure changes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am making descendant of TTreeview and I want to implement an event in the case, when the TTreeview structure changes. For example, one TTreeNode is moved from one position to another, or it becomes the child of any other TTreenode.

When I call for example: `Treeview1.Selected.MoveTo(ADropNode,naAddChildFirst);`
no event fires.

How can I catch this?

Thanx.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you fail? Right now this is only an effortless request of work to be done. Do you have the source code of `TTreeNode` and `TCustomTreeView`?

Comment: @AmigoJack I have done it, writing answer to me... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have found no message so far, what could respond to the change of structure.

The solution in this case was to make descendand of TTreeNode, where I overwrite dynamical procedure `MoveTo` and attach an event handler to it:

```
  THierarchyTreeNode = class (TTreeNode)
  private
    FOnNodeMove:TTVNodeMoveEvent;
  public
    procedure MoveTo(Destination: TTreeNode; Mode: TNodeAttachMode); override;
    property OnNodeMove:TTVNodeMoveEvent read FOnNodeMove write FOnNodeMove;
  end;
```

...

```
procedure THierarchyTreeNode.MoveTo(Destination: TTreeNode; Mode: TNodeAttachMode);
begin
   inherited;
   if Assigned(FOnNodeMove) then FOnNodeMove(Treeview, Self);
end;
```

then I have done necessary changes in  TTreeview descendand, where the procedure `CreateNode` is the key, where are `THierarchyTreeNode`s created instead of TTreenode. It is somewhat dirty, but... just an example:

```
 TTreeViewHierarchy = class(TTreeView)
private
FOnNodeMove : TTVNodeMoveEvent;
protected
    function CreateNode: TTreeNode; override;
    procedure DoNodeMove(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
published
 property OnNodeMove: TTVNodeMoveEvent read FOnNodeMove write FOnNodeMove;


function TTreeViewHierarchy.CreateNode: TTreeNode;
var
  LClass: TTreeNodeClass;
begin
  LClass := THierarchyTreeNode;
  if Assigned(OnCreateNodeClass) then
    OnCreateNodeClass(Self, LClass);
  Result := LClass.Create(Items);
  (Result as THierarchyTreeNode).FOnNodeMove := DoNodeMove;
end;

procedure TTreeViewHierarchy.DoNodeMove(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
   if Assigned(FOnNodeMove) then FOnNodeMove(Sender, Node);
end;
```

And it works...